# Controlador Laravel, extraer datos de dos tablas

Tags: sql, laravel, base-de-datos

Tengo una duda sobre cómo extraer datos de dos tablas; primero de una extraigo el listado de posts y por otro lado, extraigo de la otra el nombre del autor del post.

Tabla post

- id
- contenido
- slug
- user_id

Tabla user

- id
- name

Ambas están relacionadas, y la cosa es que funciona perfectamente extrayendo un sólo post y el nombre de su autor. Pero no para varios post y el nombre de sus autores. El controlador de un sólo post sería:

```
public function articleSHOWDETAIL($slug){
    /* Extraemos todos los post con ese slug */
    $article_show_detail = Post::where('slug', $slug)->first();
    /* Busco el nombre del usuario de la tabla user mediante el user_id del propio post */
    $article_show_detail_userid = User::where('id', ($article_show_detail->user_id))->first();
return view('guest.articles.sections.article_detail', compact('article_show_detail','article_show_detail_userid'));
}
```

Funciona perfectamente en base a lo que busco. Recibo un slug y muestro el post en la vista con su correspondiente autor (nombre de usuario).

El inconveniente lo tengo al mostrar una vista con todos los post. Hago el siguiente controlador:

```
public function articlesSHOWALL(){
    /* Extraigo todos los post existentes */
    $articles_show_all = Post::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->where('status','PUBLISHED')->paginate(6);
    /* Extraigo los nombres de usuarios contenido en el user_id de cada post */
    $articles_show_all_userid = User::where('id', ($articles_show_all->user_id));
    return view('guest.articles.articles', compact('articles_show_all','articles_show_all_userid'));
}
```

Pero me devuelve un error:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$user_id
```

Entiendo que el problema viene del paginate, pero no sé de qué forma puedo paginar los post y e imprimir el nombre del autor a la vez. He probado varias modificaciones pero ninguna sin éxito.

Answer (score 0):

El problema lo tienes con el uso de *paginate* en la primera consulta, no obtienes una colección de Eloquent de la que puedas extraer datos como lo harías normalmente.

Puedes devolver los resultados paginados a la vista. Con la primera consulta te basta:

```
$articles_show_all = Post::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->where('status','PUBLISHED')->paginate(6);
```

Luego y si "realmente las relaciones son correctas, tienes acceso al usuario relationado con cada post, por ejemplo su autor con algo como:

```
@foreach($articles_show_all as $article)
    ID autor: {{ $article->user->id }}
@endforeach
```

*Las relaciones van en los modelos.*

Answer (score 0):

Pero no es necesario tantas consultas, si tienes los modelos correctamente relacionados, ya que con paginate, `[data:[...Post]]` no existe el campo `user_id`

**Modelo POST**

```
...
public function autor(){
    return $this->belongsTo("App\User", "user_id","id");
}
...
```

las consultas serian de esta manera

**Un post**

```
//Consulta
$article_show_detail = Post::with('autor')->where('slug', $slug)->first();

//mostrar en vista |( value ?? '') validacion en caso de no existir autor
<div>Nombre: {{$article_show_detail->autor->name ?? ''}}</div>
```

**Lista de post**

```
//Consulta
$articles_show_all = Post::with('autor')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->where('status','PUBLISHED')->paginate(6);

//mostrar en vista |( value ?? '') validacion en caso de no existir autor
@foreach($articles_show_all as $article_show_detail)
<div>Nombre: {{$article_show_detail->autor->name ?? ''}}</div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Efectivamente. Es lo que buscaba. Las relaciones están bien hechas, y al emplear Model::with('autor')->orderBy('id','DESC')->where('foo','FOO'); Ese with apuntando a la tabla 'autor' resuelve y extrae el nombre. Resuelta la pregunta gracias a @user75463

Comment: @José recuerda darle al check (para marcar como respuesta) si soluciono tu problema